# Name image when buiding it from Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile and I would like the image built from it to have a name.

This doesn't work:

```
docker build -t imageName .
```

Because I get this:

```
invalid argument "imageName" for t: Error parsing reference: "imageName" is not a valid repository/tag
```

I want something like:

```
docker build --name imageName .
```

So how can I name the image?

Answer (score 5):

`docker build -t image-name:image-tag .`

Leaving off `:image-tag` will just tag it with `latest`.

Note that name components can only contain lowercase letters, digits, periods, underscores, and dashes, [as mentioned in the manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/), so your example `imageName` is invalid.

Comment: `docker build -t imageName .` doesn't work. I updated my answer to show why.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that capital letters are invalid for names. Updated.